# Indexing with Logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am working on an Elasticsearch indexing task.

Currently we are indexing hundreds of thousands of documents to ES cluster (many ES instances) on daily basis. We simply read data from DB and various of data sources, collate and compile them and directly index them to ES using python elasticsearch-dsl lib.

**Currently;**

[image: Currently]

Now we want use Logstash between the application server and ES however we don't want to change our current codebase. Thus we could easily switch between ES to Logstash and keep business logic in our application.

My question is how can I use logstash as a transparent middleware. I simply want logstash to forward all rest messages as they are to the ES cluster.

**Want to;**
[image]

Comment: http input to receive the request, then http (or elasticsearch) output to send it to elasticsearch?

Comment: @baudsp yes but how can I forward the whole request as is from input http plugin to output http plugin.